# Get all elements in JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I got a JSON file which list stocks:

```
{
  "MSFT": [
    {
      "2019-12-12 17:55:10.209859": [
        {
          "1. open": "152.4000",
          "2. high": "152.4000",
          "3. low": "152.3420",
          "4. close": "152.3750",
          "5. volume": "45689"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "2019-12-12 17:56:21.124256": [
        {
          "1. open": "152.3800",
          "2. high": "152.4100",
          "3. low": "152.3500",
          "4. close": "152.3896",
          "5. volume": "21770"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "2019-12-12 17:57:26.149805": [
        {
          "1. open": "152.3800",
          "2. high": "152.3800",
          "3. low": "152.2200",
          "4. close": "152.2250",
          "5. volume": "33914"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "2019-12-12 17:58:30.483878": [
        {
          "1. open": "152.2240",
          "2. high": "152.3675",
          "3. low": "152.0272",
          "4. close": "152.0940",
          "5. volume": "127676"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to iterate over all of the elements, and get the date too.
Like I want a data structure:

```
data = { 'date':{'open' = y, 'highest' = x, 'lowest' = z, 'close' = k, 'volume='d} }
```

How should I solve this problem?
I'm doing it for a project I have tried so many different possible ways of solutions but none worked. Please, let me know how to solve this problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html Also, your I think JSON is malformed. It should be wrapped in `[...]` so it is an array of objects.

Comment: What exactly have you tried and where a you stuck codewise?

Comment: I suggest you post a code snippet of yours , so that we can see what you have tried exactly

Comment: Why does the data list four different opening values for the same stock on the same date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to disentangle this structure, then I believe the following snippet may help you:

```
tmp = [x.popitem() for x in j_content['MSFT']]
result = dict(zip([x[0] for x in tmp], [x[1].pop() for x in tmp]))
# prints
'''
{
    '2019-12-12 17:55:10.209859': {'1. open': '152.4000', '2. high': '152.4000', '3. low': '152.3420', '4. close': '152.3750', '5. volume': '45689'},
    '2019-12-12 17:56:21.124256': {'1. open': '152.3800', '2. high': '152.4100', '3. low': '152.3500', '4. close': '152.3896', '5. volume': '21770'},
    '2019-12-12 17:57:26.149805': {'1. open': '152.3800', '2. high': '152.3800', '3. low': '152.2200', '4. close': '152.2250', '5. volume': '33914'},
    '2019-12-12 17:58:30.483878': {'1. open': '152.2240', '2. high': '152.3675', '3. low': '152.0272', '4. close': '152.0940', '5. volume': '127676'}
}
'''
```